# Extract exact characters from strings in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a function that processes some strings. I need to extract all occurrences of characters that the user provides.
example:

```r
chars.to.extract <- ";)-"
strings.to.search <- c("a;b-1","1)")
```

I need to run some function on `strings.to.search` that can return

```r
c(";-",")")
```

because those are the occurrences of `chars.to.extract` in `strings.to.search`. I have tried with

```r
gsub(paste0("[^",paste(chars.to.extract,collapse=""),"]"),"",strings.to.search)
```

The problem is that some characters in `chars.to.extract` may need escaping, others may not.

Comment: Could you give examples of those that need escaping? Everything seems to be in a character set. so already escaped

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The problem is that some characters in `chars.to.extract` may need escaping, others may not.

There will be a difference between what you actually have to escape depending on what regex library you are using.

If you plan to use base R regex function (like `gsub`) you will need to escape only `-`, `^`, `]` and `\` characters inside a character class.

If you plan to use the ICU regex engine with `stringr`/`stringi` functions (like `str_replace_all`), you will also have to escape the `[` char.

I suggest using a single escaping function for these cases:

```r
escape.charclass <- function(x) {
    gsub("([][\\\\^-])", "\\\\\\1", x)
}
```

And then you can use

```r
chars.to.extract <- ";)-"
strings.to.search <- c("a;b-1","1)")
 
escape.charclass <- function(x) {
    gsub("([][\\\\^-])", "\\\\\\1", x)
}
 
regex <- paste0("[^", escape.charclass(chars.to.extract), "]")
gsub(regex, "", strings.to.search, perl=TRUE)
## => [1] ";-" ")"
```

See the [R demo online](https://ideone.com/5cPj6B).

**NOTE**: The final `gsub` call needs the `perl=TRUE` argument as the PCRE option will treat `[[]`  and `[\[]` regular expressions as equivalent. TRE regex engine will parse the latter as a two char character class.

Comment: Thank you! I think I had to modify this line:
regex <- paste0("[^", escape.charclass(chars.to.extract), "]")
to
regex <- paste0("[^", paste(escape.charclass(chars.to.extract),collapse=""), "]")
But that was all. Thanks!